# How can I create and access custom objects in Shopify Liquid?

Tags: object, shopify, liquid

I'm working on a Shopify project and I need to create and access custom objects within my Liquid templates. I want to store additional data and manipulate it in a structured way.

How can I create a custom object with multiple properties in Shopify Liquid?
Once the object is created, how can I access its properties and values within my Liquid templates?
For example, let's say I want to create a custom object called "productData" with properties like "name", "price", and "image". How can I define and populate this object using Liquid?

Additionally, I would like to know how to access and output the values of these properties in my Liquid templates. For instance, how can I display the name and price of a product using the "productData" object?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to create, populate, and access custom objects in Shopify Liquid. Thank you in advance for your help!

Expected Result:

A code example demonstrating how to create a custom object with multiple properties in Shopify Liquid, using the "productData" object as an example.
Instructions or code snippets illustrating how to access and output the values of the "productData" object's properties within Liquid templates, allowing for displaying the name and price of a product.

Comment: Is your question related to templating only (while retrieving datas that exist) or do you want also to record datas in db?

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck. Here is the pattern for you. Shopify has built in Liquid objects it knows all about. You want to enhance those with data not in Shopify, but still present the merchant with Liquid they can edit and style? OK. So those are templates. Knowing that, you can install an App in the merchant store, and code up a Proxy. You can use that and embed a callback to the Proxy anywhere in the merchant theme where you want to render your custom Liquid. The Proxy can return Liquid! So you can accept a callback, work on a template in your App, fill in the custom data, and return that template to Shopify with any Liquid Shopify would have data for. Now Shopify accepts the Liquid from you, partially filled out by you (your custom data), and it will fill in the rest of the Liquid that it is responsible for.

Boom. Merchant gets Liquid sandwich all rendered nice. It is a neat pattern.